# SQL-Grid not support AggregationFunction

Tags: ignite

I have following sql sentence:

```
select a.age,floor(a.score) score,count(1) cnt,group_concat(a.id) ids from test_table a group by a.age,floor(a.score) having count(a.id)>10 order by a.age asc,floor(a.score) asc
```

It can be executed in IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE, but got following exception using SqlFieldsQuery:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1823)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:795)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:765)
    at com.xxx.ignite.test2.TestBinaryQuery.query(TestBinaryQuery.java:194)
    at com.xxx.ignite.test2.TestBinaryQuery.main(TestBinaryQuery.java:78)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2316)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.querySqlFields(GridQueryProcessor.java:1820)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sql.GridSqlAggregateFunction.getSQL(GridSqlAggregateFunction.java:84)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sql.GridSqlAlias.getSQL(GridSqlAlias.java:80)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sql.GridSqlSelect.getSQL(GridSqlSelect.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.sql.GridSqlQuerySplitter.split(GridSqlQuerySplitter.java:199)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryDistributedSqlFields(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1815)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$5.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:1813)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:2293)
    ... 5 more
```

I tried and found that unsupported operation is `group_concat`. Custom-SQL-Functions also not supoort aggregation like UDAF in Spark. Is it supported in future version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Aggregation functions are not supported in current releases, but they planned to be supported in the future.
Here is a ticket for this:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2177

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I think if there is a list of all supported functions desciption in some where(official doc e.g.) may be more helpful for ignite users like me. ^_^

Comment: This list preparing right now, soon it will be available